# Instagram sharing of text overlayed image using UIActivityViewController failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController and subclassing UIActivityItemSource for sharing of text and image via the apps installed on my iPhone.

After some investigation, If found that it is not possible to share "text" and "Image" with the Instagram app.

So we decided to overlay the text (Instagram caption) over the image itself (static image, in my case is Lion.png, included in the resource folder). But I find that if I were to share the "text overlayed image" using the Instagram app (displayed using UIActivityViewController), though the Instagram app launches with the image, when I enter a caption and hit the share button, though it may seem that the share was successful, but the image does not get shared.

The sharing of the modified png via the email client is successful. Not sure why Instagram is failing.

If I decide to share the original image without the "text overlay" via Instagram, the share is successful on Instagram.

Note: This below code, I have extracted from my project and put in a sample project.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "EmailItemProvider.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
             inImage:(UIImage*)  image
             atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    //    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    //    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];


    /// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

    // draw text
    [text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

- (NSString*)saveImageFile:(UIImage *)uiimage
{
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiimage);
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sample.png" ,[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    return filePath;
}

#define SEND_TO_MESSAGE @"Share via Message"
#define SEND_TO_MAIL @"Share via Mail"


- (IBAction)ShareOptions:(id)sender {


    UIImage *annotatedFile =  [self drawText: @"Referral msg with code" inImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Lion"] atPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    NSString *imageFilePath = [self saveImageFile:annotatedFile];

    NSMutableDictionary *shareOptionDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [shareOptionDic setObject:SEND_TO_MESSAGE forKey:@"1"];
    [shareOptionDic setObject:SEND_TO_MAIL forKey:@"2"];

    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pb setString:@"Referral message copied to the clipboard."];

    EmailItemProvider *emailItem = [EmailItemProvider new];
    emailItem.subject = @"sample subject";//Dummy. overridden in the delegate methods of EmailItemProvider.
    emailItem.body = @"sample body";//Dummy. overridden in the delegate methods of EmailItemProvider.


    //Image with the text overlay. When this image is used, the Instagram share fails.
    emailItem.imagePath = imageFilePath;

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[emailItem]
                                      applicationActivities:nil];


    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    return;
}


@end
```

The class EmailItemProvider is subclassed from UIActivityItemSource and it's .h and .m is provided below.

```
//
//  EmailItemProvider.h
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EmailItemProvider : NSObject <UIActivityItemSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *body;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;//dummy
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imagePath;//image path with text overlay
@end



//
//  EmailItemProvider.m
//  
//

#import "EmailItemProvider.h"

@implementation EmailItemProvider

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {

    //This code works.
    //return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lion"];

    //Returning an text overlayed image for Instagram share doesnot work.
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.imagePath];
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    NSLog(@"one %@", activityType);


    //This code which return an image overlayed with text, instagram share fails.
    return @{@"text": @"Referral information goes here.", @"image": [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.imagePath]};


    //I am able to share Instagram share when I comment the above code and uncomment the below code.
    //return @{@"text": @"Referral information goes here.", @"image": [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lion"]};
}


- (nullable UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(nullable UIActivityType)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size; // if activity supports preview image. iOS 7.0
{

    NSLog(@"two activity type : %@\n", activityType);
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lion"];

}


- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {

    NSLog(@"three %@", activityType);
    return @"subject text";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue was because of the image size. The Instagram share was failing when the source image (super imposed with text) was 236 × 374.

But when I used an 442 × 620 png image as the base image, I was able to share the image after superimposing the text.

Though one question remains unanswered. How is that the vanilla 236 × 374 image (without the text superimposition) being shared successfully via Instagram?

Comment: I have observed when we write text on the image programmatically and save it, sometimes its resolution gets doubled, so we have to be so sure the image is getting saved in proper resolutions.